# android firebase onDataChange taking bit more time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase real time database in my android mobile app programme and the onDataChange method taking bit time to return results. I believe onDataChange is asynchronous method, taking  bit more time to respond.  how do I get response back quicker from firebase json db.

```
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            ocation.longitude+ ":ended");
                primaryKey = key;
                        geoAsynHash.put(key,location );


                        ref.child(techCategory).child(primaryKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                             }
```

}
}

Comment: There is no "quicker way" to get data back from Firebase. If there was, that would be the way the SDK exposed it. What problem do you have with the code you shared?

Comment: What do you mean through "taking bit time"?

Comment: thank you. firstly, I don't have any problem with the code I shared. I wanted to check with developer community to see if there is an alternative way to get data back from Firebase faster.

Comment: I am reading data from Firebase. once I have trigged an action, I get response from Firebase after 5 seconds.